# Python clicking game, updating score

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import time
pygame.init()


randomNumber = random.randint(1,600)
randomNumber2 = random.randint(1,600)
x = 0
text = ""
squareCount = 0
beenHere = 0
# colours = (red, green, blue)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
LBLUE = (0, 123, 255)

colour = RED

# Make a window appear
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Square Chase | Score: 0")
screen.fill(LBLUE)
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 1500)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while done == False:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print(event)
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
    if event.type == USEREVENT + 1:
        screen.fill(LBLUE)
        randomNumber = random.randint(1,625)
        randomNumber2 = random.randint(1,420)
        mySquare = pygame.draw.rect(screen,colour,(randomNumber,randomNumber2,50,50),5)
        squareCount = squareCount + 1
        if squareCount == 50:
            done == true
        pygame.display.flip()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        y, z = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        is_inside = mySquare.collidepoint(y, z)
        if is_inside and colour == GREEN:
            x = x+1
            text = str(x)
            pygame.display.set_caption("Square Chase | Score " + text)
            colour = RED
        elif is_inside:
            x = x+1
            text = str(x)
            pygame.display.set_caption("Square Chase | Score " + text)
            colour = GREEN
clock.tick(20)
pygame.quit()
```

I am aiming to create a game in which the user has to click on a square for their score to increase. They get 50 chances to do this. If they click in the square within the 1.5 seconds the colour of the square changes.

The above code works apart from each time a new square is drawn the user could click on it say 5 times and their score will go up by 5. Any suggestions as to how to get the score to increase by just one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wish I could just use a comment but I have lack of reputation.

I didn't look through all your code, but your description makes it sound like a simple flag would be able to help you.

Once you recognize it has been clicked, increment the score AND set a boolean.

So in essence you will want something along the lines of

```
if clicked == false
     score = score+1
     clicked = true
```

You will want to clear the flag back to false once another block has appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better, if a new square would show up after a successful keypress? That way the game would be more dynamic.

It's easy to change this. Instead of using user events that are called every 1.5 sec, sum the value returned by clock.tick() and when their sum will be greater than 1500 ms, create a new rectangle. This is a better approach, because you can call the method that creates a new square and reset the timer right after a successful keypress.

Some code to get you started:

```
def new_rect(screen,colour):
    screen.fill(LBLUE)
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,625)
    randomNumber2 = random.randint(1,420)
    mySquare = pygame.draw.rect(screen,colour,(randomNumber,randomNumber2,50,50),5)
    return mySquare

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
timer_var = 0

while done == False:
    if(timer_var > 1500):
        timer_var = 0
        mySquare = new_rect(screen,color)
        squareCount = squareCount + 1
        if squareCount == 50:
            done == true

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            y, z = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            is_inside = mySquare.collidepoint(y, z)
            if is_inside: 
                x = x+1
                text = str(x)
                pygame.display.set_caption("Square Chase | Score " + text)

                timer_var = 0
                new_rect(screen,colour)
                squareCount = squareCount + 1
                if squareCount == 50:
                    done == true
                if colour == GREEN:
                    colour = RED
                else:
                    colour = GREEN
    timer_var += clock.tick(20)
pygame.quit()
```